# Из множества одинакових HTML елементов, удалить только нажатый

Tags: javascript, html, dom

У меня блок состоит из 25 одинаковых элементов, и на каждый из них я наложил onclick, чтобы в js написать функцию удаления этого элемента. Но при нажатии на любой из этих элементов удаляется только первый, а не нажатый. Как это исправить, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
<div class="matches_block">
        <div class="match" onclick="disappear()">
            <div class="head_match"></div>
            <div class="body_math"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="match" onclick="disappear()">
            <div class="head_match"></div>
            <div class="body_math"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="match" onclick="disappear()">
            <div class="head_match"></div>
            <div class="body_math"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="match" onclick="disappear()">
            <div class="head_match"></div>
            <div class="body_math"></div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
function disappear(){
const match = document.querySelector('.match');
match.classList.toggle('active');}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function disappear(element) {  
  element.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: blue;
}

.match {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="matches_block">
  <div class="match" onclick="disappear(this)">
    <div class="head_match"></div>
    <div class="body_math"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="match" onclick="disappear(this)">
    <div class="head_match"></div>
    <div class="body_math"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="match" onclick="disappear(this)">
    <div class="head_match"></div>
    <div class="body_math"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="match" onclick="disappear(this)">
    <div class="head_match"></div>
    <div class="body_math"></div>
  </div>
```